# How can I stop the submit button from stacking under the text field on a bootstrap form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQQpyg

On a larger screen this isn't a problem, but when I reduce the browser window, the submit button moves underneath the text field. 
This is causing a problem when I try to add a background color to the form with css. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
      <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @SilencePeace that has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/2zkwxm97/

Added `col-xs-4` to `<div class="form-group col-xs-4">`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a horizontal form with column sizing.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.less-padding {
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-6 less-padding">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 less-padding">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32510231/1255289) was mentioned.

Here is how it goes:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sure, no problem. I have added a container and row div, with several col sizes. So the input field will not expand it's width too much on larger screens.

Answer (score 1):

class `.form-inline` only applies to forms within viewports that are at least **768px** wide.

Check Bootstrap Doc [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

To achieve what you want, you shouldn't use it. You could do something like this:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tinmarin60/ew8rb9f7/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it uses a media query like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
```

And anything narrower than that, the `form-group` will change to `display:block` instead of `inline-block`. So maybe override that back to `inline-block`, but not sure that is best way to solve your issue. Maybe let it stack like that and find another way to fix the background color issue.